# Is this correct way of update query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I got some problems with finding a bug in php/mysql application, and I wonder if I can do something like this: `UPDATE table SET userid='2' WHERE userid='1'` - > Can I update something I state in WHERE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely.  You can even reference the current value of the column in the set:

UPDATE table
SET x = x + 5
WHERE x < 3

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem, and you can do a lot [more](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)...